# Group by a many-to-many relashionship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two entities:

```
public class Category
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Based on a set of Address Id's, I need to Group By all the addresses by Category, including the Address Count for each Address.

Example:

```
Category: {1,"WORKSHOP",{1,2}},{2,"DEALER",{1,3}}

Address:  {1,"Paul Workshop and Dealer",{1,2}}
          {2,"Joe Workshop",{1}} 
          {3,"Peter Dealer",{2}}
```

If I have the Address Id's 1 and 3, I want to get:

```
Categories - "WORKSHOP -  Count: 1"
             "DEALER   -  Count: 2"
```

If I have the Address Id's 1 and 2, I want to get: Category -

```
Categories - "WORKSHOP -  Count: 2"
             "DEALER   -  Count: 1"
```

So far I get this, but the group by is not working:

```
var groupedAddresses = from add in addressQuery
                       where addressIds.Contains(add.Id)
                       group add by new { Category_Id = add.Categories, Address_Id = add.Id };

var result = from add in groupedAddresses 
             group add by add.Id into final
             join c in categoryQuery on final.Key equals c.Id
             select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
             {
                   Id = final.Key,
                   Name = c.Name,
                   SearchCount = final.Count()
              };
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you have `"DEALER   -  Count: 1"` for address ids 1 and 3? Dealer has both addresses provided. Looks like count should be 2

Comment: Hi, Thanks, when I was rechecking the question I saw this mistake, and I have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] addressIds = { 1, 3 };

var query = from c in categoryQuery
            let searchCount = c.Addresses.Count(a => addressIds.Contains(a.Id))
            where searchCount > 0
            select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto{
               Id = c.Id,
               Name = c.Name,
               SearchCount = searchCount
            };
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! But it's returning all the Categories, including the ones that have SearchCount = 0, how can I change your solution to get only the ones with Count > 0 ? Thanks again

Comment: @Patrick updated, you can use additional query variable for that

Comment: Simply amazing! My smile is from one side to the other of the office :) Thank you so much for your kind help, and the way and speed you have done it, it's just fantastic

Comment: @Patrick u r welcome :) Learn [LINQ](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html) it's very powerful tool

Comment: hi! Hope you can help on this, I would like to include in the select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto{} the possibility to have all the "addressIds" for each Category, any idea? I have tried " Ids = c.Addresses.Where(a => addressIds.Contains(a.Id)).Select(a => a.Id).ToList()" but no luck :(

Comment: I get base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}. Is this will filter the AddressIds for each Category?

Comment: @Patrick try to define `Ids` as `IEnumerable<int>` and do not call `ToList()`

Comment: Hi! Thanks it's working :) but why I have to store it in an IEnumerable and I can't store it in a List() ?

Comment: @Patrick because EF generates plain SQL query which returns all values required for all properties in your select statement. E.g. for your query it will select something like `SELECT Id, Name, Id1, Name1` and will map these results to `CategoryGetAllBySearchDto` on client side. Main idea here is that code, which selects value for each property in result should be converted into SQL and executed on server side. EF cannot convert `ToList()` call into SQL

Comment: Ok, I got it! :) the issue here is that I need to send back to the View the list of Ids and store them in an hidden input, so I have to make a convertion to the format "id1,id2,id3,..."

Comment: Hi Sergey, I found an issue with your solution, I am getting all the Categories that match the Address Id's, and I can only get the categories for the Addresses that match the Keywords, any ideia how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Patrick that's not issue - thats a filtering by intent. Just remove `where searchCount > 0`

Comment: I'm getting all the 0 count categories, all the categories that match the keywords, etc....